# Flutter: dynamic platform icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Recently I started using this library and works great:
https://github.com/stryder-dev/flutter_platform_widgets

But unfortunately it doesn't support many icons for iOS. Is there any option out there to have dynamic icons for both platforms?